# Separate Columns Using Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column titled "File Name" that contains lengthy strings that I need to break into different columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'File Name':['92.00.88 / Z.89 / JK89Y3333 Test File Name', 
                                 '94.00.21 / W.22 / JK89Y3333 Sample Document Title Here', 
                                 '94.10.31 / Y.88 / JK89Y3333 File Document Name',
                                 'Phase 1',
                                 'Phase 2']}) 

| File Name                                              |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 92.00.88 / Z.89 / JK89Y3333 Test File Name             |
| 94.00.21 / W.22 / JK89Y3333 Sample Document Title Here |
| 94.10.31 / Y.88 / JK89Y3333 File Document Name         |
| Phase 1                                                |
| Phase 2                                                |
```

This is what I need the DataFrame to look like:

```
| File Number | Site | Barcode   | Title                      | Phase   |
|-------------|------|-----------|----------------------------|---------|
| 92.00.88    | Z.89 | JK89Y3333 | Test File Name             |         |
| 94.00.21    | W.22 | JK89Y3333 | Sample Document Title Here |         |
| 94.10.31    | Y.88 | JK89Y3333 | File Document Name         |         |
|             |      |           |                            | Phase 1 |
|             |      |           |                            | Phase 2 |
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this using RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df['File Name'].str.extract(r'(?P<File_Number>.*)\s/\s(?P<Site>.*)\s/\s(?P<Barcode>.*?)\s(?P<Tile>.*)|(?P<Phase>Phase.*)'). \
    fillna(''). \
    rename(columns={'File_Number':'File Number'})

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  File Number  Site    Barcode                        Tile    Phase
0    92.00.88  Z.89  JK89Y3333              Test File Name         
1    94.00.21  W.22  JK89Y3333  Sample Document Title Here         
2    94.10.31  Y.88  JK89Y3333          File Document Name         
3                                                           Phase 1
4                                                           Phase 2
```

Comment: wow what an amazing regex, how do you even come up with that. I don't think you need `expand` in `extract`

Comment: what does the `?P` mean in the regex?

Comment: @Kenan It's *named group*, it seems Pandas will use this name as column name - I've just read it in the docs from [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract) - It's in the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) module docs too

Answer (score 1):

We can use negative- and positive lookahead for some advanced splitting:

```
data = df['File Name'].str.split('/|(?<=\d{3})\s(?=[A-Z])', expand=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data.to_numpy(), columns=['File Number', 'Site', 'Barcode', 'Title'])

# clean up File Number column and create Phase columns
phase = df2['File Number'].str.contains('Phase')
df2.loc[phase, 'Phase'] = df2.loc[phase, 'File Number']
df2.loc[phase, 'File Number'] = ''
df2 = df2.replace(np.NaN, '')

  File Number    Site     Barcode                       Title    Phase
0   92.00.88    Z.89    JK89Y3333              Test File Name         
1   94.00.21    W.22    JK89Y3333  Sample Document Title Here         
2   94.10.31    Y.88    JK89Y3333          File Document Name         
3                                                              Phase 1
4                                                              Phase 2
```